# Adjusting elements in html and css

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am wondering how I can align the asterisk symbol with the text and lower the Yes and No elements as shown in the image.

[image]

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07bd0hda/ and snippet below:

```html
<div class="dependents-covered-elsewhere">
  <div class="dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk">*</div>
  <label data-bind="text: i18n('dependents.coveredElsewhere')">Is the dependent covered elsewhere?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="1" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled="">
  <div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
  </div>

  <label>
    <!-- ko i18n:'yes' -->Yes
    <!-- /ko -->
  </label>

  <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="0" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled="">
  <div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
  </div>


  <label>
    <!-- ko i18n:'no' -->No
    <!-- /ko -->
  </label>
</div>
```

The CSS which I have used:

```
.dependents-covered-elsewhere {
    max-width: 340px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: the posistion has more to do with your markup than the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a span for your * since a span is native to display inline

I then added a css rule with the pseudo class for first-of-type to only apply to the first label and set it to display block

```css
.dependents-covered-elsewhere label:first-of-type {
  display:block;
  }




.dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="dependents-covered-elsewhere">
   
     <label data-bind="text: i18n('dependents.coveredElsewhere')">Is the dependent covered elsewhere? <span class="dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk">*</span></label>
       <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="1" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled=""><div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
</div>

<label><!-- ko i18n:'yes' -->Yes<!-- /ko --></label>
        
        <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="0" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled=""><div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
</div>
 
        
        <label><!-- ko i18n:'no' -->No<!-- /ko --></label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update & re-order your HTML markup by adding `<div>` on options and `<span>` on asterisk.

Have a look at the snippet below or look at the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07bd0hda/1/):

```html
<div class="dependents-covered-elsewhere">
     <label data-bind="text: i18n('dependents.coveredElsewhere')">Is the dependent covered elsewhere?</label>
     <span class="dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk">*</span>
     <div class="option-holder">
       <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="1" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled=""><div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
</div>

<label><!-- ko i18n:'yes' -->Yes<!-- /ko --></label>
        
        <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="0" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled=""><div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
</div>
 
        
        <label><!-- ko i18n:'no' -->No<!-- /ko --></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

All that you have to do is make the div that holds the asterisk a span element:

```html
<div class="dependents-covered-elsewhere">
  <span class="dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk">*</span>
  <label data-bind="text: i18n('dependents.coveredElsewhere')">Is the dependent covered elsewhere?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="1" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled="">
  <div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
  </div>

  <label>
    <!-- ko i18n:'yes' -->Yes
    <!-- /ko -->
  </label>

  <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="0" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled="">
  <div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
  </div>


  <label>
    <!-- ko i18n:'no' -->No
    <!-- /ko -->
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet is right there, it is aligned, also, if you want it to be on the other side, just move it after the other element in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Would this suffice?

CSS:
 `.dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk { float: left; }`

Comment: It is still extreme left ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the many ways to do this - not changing your markup:

1. Absolutely position the `asterick` to the right of the label
2. Drop the yes-or-no checkboxes by `display: block`

See demo below:

```css
.dependents-covered-elsewhere {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk + label {
  display: block;
}
.dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="dependents-covered-elsewhere">
  <div class="dependents-covered-elsewhere-asterisk">*</div>
  <label data-bind="text: i18n('dependents.coveredElsewhere')">Is the dependent covered elsewhere?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="1" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled="">
  <div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
  </div>

  <label>
    <!-- ko i18n:'yes' -->Yes
    <!-- /ko -->
  </label>

  <input type="radio" name="coveredElsewhere" value="0" data-bind="checked: coveredElsewhereForBinding, enable: !(isTab() &amp;&amp; emprel_id &amp;&amp; vm.home.action() == 'life-events')" disabled="">
  <div data-bind="visible: field.isModified() &amp;&amp; !field.isValid(), attr: {title: field.error}" class="info" style="display: none;">
  </div>


  <label>
    <!-- ko i18n:'no' -->No
    <!-- /ko -->
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. One quick question. When I am inspecting `<div class="dependents-covered-elsewhere"> </div>`, why its not covering the asterisk symbol ?

Comment: when you position absolutely, it is taken out of the flow, that's why... I would suggest you to drop the `asterick` below the `label` and *not* do positioning... becasue there are simpler ways (see other answers)... This as I said, *one of the many options*